# background shadow for UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

How can I make a background under a UIBarButtonItem like this top left button: [image]

Answer (score 2):

You should tell your designer to create that type of button image.

Answer (score 1):

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
UINavigationBar.appearance().layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 1)
UINavigationBar.appearance().layer.shadowRadius = 3
UINavigationBar.appearance().layer.shadowOpacity = 1
```